# Split a string in object property and make new dataset

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have a dataset where the last item is a string in the form of a sentence.  My goal is to split the sentence into words, and create a new dataset where each word is on its own line, as illustrated below:

Here is the format of the old dataset:
​

```
0: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "The cat in the hat ate the rat", … }
1: Object { creator: "may", number: 4, doc: "the crass rat", … }
2: Object { creator: "may", number: 4, doc: "The mouse in the pouch at the cat", … }
3: Object { creator: "may", number: 4, doc: "the fish hog", … }
4: Object { creator: "may", number: 4, doc: "the dog warm", … }
```

Here is the format I am aiming for:

```
0: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "The", … }
1: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "cat", … }
2: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "in", … }
3: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "the", … }
4: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "hat", … }
5: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "ate", … }
6: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "the", … }
7: Object { creator: "molly", number: 3, doc: "rat", … }
8: Object { creator: "may", number: 4, doc: "the", … }
9: Object { creator: "may", number: 4, doc: "crass", … }
10: Object { creator: "may", number: 4, doc: "rat", … }
```

I am using D3.  The following code has allowed me to generate a new dataset where each word is on it own line:

doc.csv:

```
    date,number,creator,,doc
6/16/2000,3,molly,3,The cat in the hat ate the rat
2/25/2002,4,may,2,The mouse in the pouch at the cat
12/5/2004,3,molly,4,the lovely fish
7/6/2006,1,milly,1,the pog dog
9/7/2003,4,may,4,the fish hog
12/10/2001,4,may,3,the crass rat
6/15/2005,2,maggie,3,the ass rat
6/9/2004,1,milly,4,the fish blue
10/5/2005,1,milly,3,the rat true
10/7/2003,4,may,1,the dog warm
1/19/2009,4,may,2,the cat norm
10/30/2007,1,milly,4,the fish wish
8/13/2009,4,may,2,cat bat ticks
9/30/2004,3,molly,1,dog nog mog
1/17/2006,4,may,3,rat tittily too
12/18/2009,3,molly,1,dog coppily poo
11/2/2007,2,maggie,3,rat pitpat poo
4/17/2007,1,milly,4,fish too!
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta chartset="utf-8">
        <title>Interactive scatterplot</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v4.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="split.js"></script>

<textarea id="txtName" name="txt-Name" placeholder="Search for something.." rows="1"></textarea>


</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

code:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

    var hoot = function(d) {return d.doc.split(" ").forEach(function (item) {
        var data2 = {creator: d.creator, date: parseDate(d.date),item: item}
        console.log(data2)
    });}



    d3.csv("doc.csv")
      .row(function(d) {return {creator: d.creator,date: parseDate(d.date),number: Number(d.number),doc: d.doc, split: (hoot(d))};})
      .get(function(error, data) {

    });
```

Happily, when I console.log data2, I get something approximating my end goal:

[image]

I have two problems:

1) The variable `data2` is not available after the function runs.  I tried to make `data2` a global variable by putting `var data2 = [];` at the beginning of the script, but this does not work.

2) The variable `data2` does not take the form of a single array.  I tried putting square brackets around the variable line (ie. `var data2 = [{creator: d.creator, date: parseDate(d.date),item: item}]`), but this makes many arrays, rather than a single array.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `data2` is a local variable inside the `foreach` loop. So, even if you make it global you will only get the value during the last iteration. Instead, you can make `data2` an array and `push` values into it during each iteration. It might look something like this

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");
var data2 = [];
    var hoot = function(d) {return d.doc.split(" ").forEach(function (item) {
       data2.push({creator: d.creator, date: parseDate(d.date),item: item})
    });}
console.log(data2);



    d3.csv("doc.csv")
      .row(function(d) {return {creator: d.creator,date: parseDate(d.date),number: Number(d.number),doc: d.doc, split: (hoot(d))};})
      .get(function(error, data) {

    });
```

Now console log it and see, hope you will get expected results.